# Having an error when fetching request of Core Data

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, swift3, multipeer-connectivity

I want to store some new data in core data. Most of the times it works, but it gives an error of

```
[error] error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  *** Collection <__NSCFSet: 0x16eb6a50> was mutated while being enumerated. with userInfo (null)

CoreData: error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  *** Collection <__NSCFSet: 0x16eb6a50> was mutated while being enumerated. with userInfo (null)
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <__NSCFSet: 0x16eb6a50> was mutated while being enumerated.'


*** First throw call stack:

(0x1deefb3d 0x1d177067 0x1deef5e1 0x1fea4bbb 0x1fe8a863 0x1fe89be5 0x1fe68da9 0x9403ec 0x8cefc 0x137ed0 0x134530 0x13790c 0x126ab0 0xd0be0 0xd3a467 0xd3a453 0xd3ed47 0x1deabd69 0x1dea9e19 0x1ddfd1af 0x1ddfcfd1 0x1f5a7b41 0x2317fa53 0x8e068 0x1d5ea4eb)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

occasionally.

Here are the codes of getData in AppDelegate

```
func getData(request: NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>) -> Any{
    do {
        let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
        let results = try context.fetch(request)
        return results
    } catch {
        let nserror = error as NSError
        fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

I discovered that it breaks at `let results = try context.fetch(request)`. I wonder if there is any problem with this line or other lines?

Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: you made any changes in coredata structure? If you made changes then you have to delete existing app and install new app to get those changes

Comment: Yes, I did make some changes but I didn't reinstall the app. I tried to reinstall the app and it seems working now. Not sure if it is related to my coding problem or re-installation problem. Anyway, thx for ur help.

Comment: No, there is no coding error. It seems that coredata structure need to update your app everytime you change.

Comment: I see. I was thinking why it pops up the error occasionally and have no ways to reproduce it. Thx for your great help.